# Java saving file under same name in same directory with different extension

Tags: java, file-io

I'm writing a *very* basic java program that takes a file, does some modifications and saves the output in a different file. My problem is that I would like to save it under the same name, but with a different extension.

My current code gets the original file using the JFileChooser, converts it to a path, and uses the .resolveSibling() method. This, however, will result in **test.ngc**'s output being saved in **test.ngc.fnc**

Is there any good way to save a file under the same name, but with a diffrent extension as the one selected?

```
Path originalFile = null;

JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(".ngc");
chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Pycam G Code files", "ngc"));
if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
    originalFile = chooser.getSelectedFile().toPath();
}

Path newFile = originalFile.resolveSibling(originalFile.getFileName() + ".fnc");

/* does reading and modification and saving here using BufferedReader and BufferedWriter*/
```

Comment: Remove the extension from the original file name first. substring() is your friend. Read the String javadoc.

Comment: I was hoping that Path would have an undocumented method for that, as there are so many edge cases and it seemed a useful thing to have. :( toString() it is, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
String originalFilename = originalFile.getFileName();
String fileNameNew = originalFilename.substring(0, originalFilename.length()-".ngc".length())+".fnc";
Path newFile = originalFile.resolveSibling(fileNameNew);
```

Answer (score 1):

To save the output in a different file with a different extension (`.fnc`), you can use `regex`(regular expression) to replace that using the `replaceFirst` method:

```
    Path originalFile ;
    String pathName ;

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(".ngc");
    chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Pycam G Code files", "ngc"));
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        originalFile = chooser.getSelectedFile().toPath();

        pathName = originalFile.toAbsolutePath().toString().replaceFirst("\\b.ngc\\b", "");

        Path newFile = originalFile.resolveSibling(pathName + ".fnc");
        File file = new File(newFile.toUri());
        file.createNewFile();
    }
```